# object reference not set to an instance of an object - different behaviour on different systems

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf

ive got a problem that threw my knowlegde in programming a few years back :)

How is it possible that everything works fine on my developping machine and on other testing machines but on the slight different target system it just wont run properly.

I'm trying to open a database connection to a MSSQLSERVER. However it is not going to happen. The exception is threwing a "object reference not set to an instance of an object..." (like i mentioned only on the target system, everywhere else there is no problem)

The exceptions is pointing on the connection.Open() line in the following code.

```
    private void openConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = getConnectionString();
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I compared the systems. They are nearly the same except of some security policies.
Both are win7 64bit with the same .net version

I hope somebody can help me with this mistery.

Thanks in advance

edit: ive added the connection string an the stacktrace.... maybe it can help anyone to help me.[image: connection string]

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: The full stack trace will likely give you more information. For example a connection string may be missing from your config.

Comment: The security policies are the most likely the cause of the issue. Your connection string seems null, probably the `getConnectionString()` method isn't able (for security rights) to read the config file.

Comment: i dont have access to the stack trace right now. i also tried it with a hard coded connection string. that is not the fault part.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: ctor of SqlConnection accepts null or empty string without throwing an exception. Calling Open() then results in an InvalidOperationException. So it is very unlikely that Open() throws a NullReferenceException.

Comment: MSSQL Server 2012. its running on a virtual machine with win server 2012 r2. but i dont think its the db causing the error. i tried the   same application from an other pc. no error was thrown there

Comment: i also tried a simple connection. now ive got "accessviolationexception: attempted to read or write protected memory" maybe these faults going hand by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Check if "connection" is null after the "new Connection" line and throw an exception if it is.

You probably have some variation in the connection string in your environments, which you have failed to address. Test the connection string using a command line database client from the server where this should run; it will likely not connect.

Comment: I have displayed the connection string. It seems like all others I used to get a connection to the db. But i will try ofc.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! I just had to update the .NET version to 4.5.2 and everything works just fine.
After running some other tests i found out that the real exception was accessviolationexception and somehow it seems that it was covered by the nullreferenceexception. however i still dont know why other system didnt had these problems with .NET version 4.5.1 but after days of debugging i just dont care. thanks a lot for all your advices

greets